# Prove that if $f:M\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is a scalar function over a 1-manifold M without boundary then $\int_M df=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem, compact-manifolds

Well James Munkres in the text *Analysis on Manifolds* prove the general Stoke's theorem for $k$-form when $k>1$ and then he proves it for $k=1$ only when the bounary of the Manifold is not empty and he leaves as exercise to show that if $f$ is a scalar function defined over a compact $1$-manifold $M$ then
$$
\int_M df=0
$$

So let's start to try to prove it and precisely we will do to scalar function whose support is covered by a single coordinate chart becasue as Munkres showed in the general proof this is sufficent. Indeed if $\Phi:\{\phi_i:i=1,...,l\}$ is a partition of unity dominated by the coordinate patches of $M$ then the support of the forn $\phi_i\omega$ is contained in a single coordinate patch for each $i=1,..,l$ and thus
$$
\int_Md\omega=\int_M0+\int_Md\omega=\int_M0\curlywedge\omega+\int_M\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^l\phi_i\Biggl)\curlywedge d\omega=
\\
\int_Md1\curlywedge\omega+\int_M\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^l\phi_i\curlywedge d\omega\Bigg)=
\\
\int_Md\Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^l\phi_i\Biggl)\curlywedge\omega+\sum_{i=1}^l\Biggl(\int_M\phi_i\curlywedge d\omega\Biggl)=
\\
\sum_{i=1}^l\Biggl(\int_Md\phi_i\curlywedge\omega\Biggl)+\sum_{i=1}^l\Biggl(\int_M(-1)^0\phi_i\curlywedge d\omega\Biggl)=\sum_{i=1}^l\Biggl(\int_Md\phi_i\curlywedge\omega+\int_M(-1)^0\phi_i\curlywedge d\omega\Biggl)
\\
\sum_{i=1}^l\Biggl(\int_Md\phi_i\curlywedge\omega+(-1)^0\phi_i\curlywedge d\omega\Biggl)=\sum_{i=1}^l\int_Md(\phi_i\omega)=0
$$

Well if $M$ is a compact $1$-manifold without boundary it is possible to prove that for any $p\in M$ there exist a coordinate patch $\alpha$ defined in the unitary positive interval $(0,1)$ and thus if $f:M\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is a scalar function defined over M whose support $S_f$ is covered by a single coordinate patch then
$$
\int_Mdf:=\int_{(0,1)}\alpha^*(df)=\int_{(0,1)}d(\alpha^*f)=\int_{(0,1)}d(\alpha\circ f)
$$
So Unfortunately I do not able to prove that
$$
\int_{(0,1)}d(\alpha\circ f)=0
$$
and thus I ask to do it. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you know that it is sufficient to prove this for a scalar function $f$ with support $K$ contained in a coordinate open $U$, then $df$ also has support in $U$, say in $K'$. Now, let $\phi:(a,b)\to U$ be a parametrization. The integral in this case is defined by
$$
\int_a^b\phi^*(df)=\int_a^bd(\phi^*f).
$$
I think you also reached this conclusion. Write $g=\phi^*f$. Then $dg=g'(x)dx$. So, we have
$$
\int_a^b\phi^*(df)=\int_a^bd(\phi^*f)=\int_a^bg'(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)
$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now, as $K\subsetneq U$, $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a proper subset of $(a,b)$ and hence does *not* contain $a$ or $b$. So, $g(b)=g(a)=0$. So
$$
\int_a^b\phi^*(df)=\int_a^bd(\phi^*f)=\int_a^bg'(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)=0.
$$

Comment: Oh yeah! Only one question. To be precisely it shall be $$\int_a^bg'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(b-a+x)-g(x)$$ because $\phi$ is not defined on $a$ and $b$, right?

Comment: Anyway could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033392/does-two-different-extensions-of-a-map-between-manifolds-have-the-same-derivativ), please?

Comment: Regarding your first question, yes. I was just a bit lazy.

Comment: I will look at the other question when I can!

Comment: Oh, thanks! I am waiting for your answer.