# Prove that the tangent space of a submanifold is a subspace of the tangent space of the manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, diffeomorphism

So I ask if $M$ and $N$ are $k$-manifold and $h$-manifold of $\Bbb R^n$ respectively such that $N\subseteq M$ then the tangent space in $N$ at $y\in N$ is a subspace of the tangent space in $M$. So if $N=\partial M$ the result is surely true but otherwise I do not know.

> So to prove it I covered $M$ by carefully-chosen coordinate patches. As a first case for $y\in M\setminus\partial M$ we choose a coordinate patch $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ about $y_0$ such that $U$ is open in $\Bbb R^k$ and contains the unit cube $(0,1)^k$ and such that $\alpha$ carries a point of $(0,1)^{h}\times\{0\}^{k-h}$ to $y_0$: if we begin with an arbitrary coordinate patch $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ about $y_0$ we can obtain one of the desired type be preceding $\alpha$ by a translation and a stretching in $\Bbb R^k$. As second case for $y_0\in\partial M$ we choose a coordinate patch $\alpha:U\rightarrow V$ such that $U$ is open in $H^k$ and $U$ contains $(0,1)^k$ and such that $\alpha$ carries a point of $(0,1)^{h}\times\{0\}^{k-h}$ to the point $y_0$. Exactly we can do this choosing a close rectangle $C:=\prod_{i=1}^k[a_i,b_i]$ about $\alpha^{-1}(y_0)$ contained in $U$ and so defining a diffeomorphism $\phi:\Bbb R^k\rightarrow\Bbb R^k$ in any $x\in\Bbb R^k$ such that $\phi[C]=[0,1]^k$ and $\phi(x_0)\in\Bbb R^h\times\{0\}^{k-h}$. Indeed if $\psi$ is the inverse of $\phi$ then $\alpha\circ\psi$ is the coordinate patch of the type described above.
>
> So in any case if $\alpha$ is a coordinate patch of $M$ about $y\in N$ then $y=\alpha(x)$ for $x\in U\cap\Bbb R^h\times\{0\}^{k-h}$ and thus if $U_0\subseteq\Bbb R^h$ is an open set such that $U\cap\Bbb R^h\times\{0\}^{k-h}=U_0\times\{0\}^{k-h}$ then the map $\alpha\circ\iota$ is a coordinate patch of $N$ at $y$ where $\iota$ is the natural embedding of $\Bbb R^h$ in $\Bbb R^k$. So we observe that the column of the derivative of $\alpha\circ\iota$ are exactly the first $h$ column of the derivative of $\alpha$ and thus the statement follows.

So as you can see I did not able to construct the map $\phi$. In particular I tried to define it at $x\in\Bbb R^k$ trough the equation
$$
\big[\phi(x)\big](i)\:=\frac{x_i-a_i}{b_i-a_i}
$$
for each $i=1,...,k$ but generally $\phi(x_0)\notin\Bbb R^h\times\{0\}^{k-h}$ where $x_0=\alpha^{-1}(y_0)$, although $\phi[C]=[0,1]^k$. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a coordinate-free proof. Consider the inclusion $i : N \to M$. As $N$ is a submanifold, $i$ is an embedding, and for each $p \in N$, its differential $\mathrm{d}i_p : T_p N \to T_pM$ is injective, and identifies $T_pN$ as a linear subspace $\mathrm{d}i_p(T_pN) \subset T_pM$.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not really understand becasuse as you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033392/does-two-different-extensions-of-a-map-between-manifolds-have-the-same-derivativ) I have some difficult to define the differential of a function between manifolds. Anyway perhaps I found another simple solution.

Comment: So a vector $\vec v$ is a tangent vector $M$ at $p\in M$ if and only if there exist a parametrized-curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ whose image set lies in $M$ such that $\vec v$ is equals to the velocity vector of $\gamma$ corresponding to the parameter value $t=0$. So if $N\subseteq M$ obviously any parametrized curve in $N$ is a parametrized curve in $M$ and so the result follows trivially. Is my last argument correct?

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct

Comment: Okay, if you add it you put it in your answer adding some comments I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is using another, less computational method, but here's another/simpler way to see it:

$N$ is a submanifold of $M$, so there is an inclusion map $i : N \hookrightarrow M$. We can use that map to "push forward" tangent vectors of $N$ to tangent vectors of $M$.

This can simply be done by considering the jacobian induced by $i$ (call it $Di|$), which, at any $x \in N$, is a smooth map from $T_xN$ to $T_xM$. All you need to show
then is that it is injective, which will imply that $Di|_x(T_xN) \leq T_xM$.

The last step is identifying $Di|_x(T_xN)$ with $T_xN$, because both spaces are isomorphic by construction.